# Dynamic where expression to use in linq

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates

I want to build a dynamic where expression to use over a list of objects.

```
var list = new List<Dummy>();
IQueryable<Dummy> queryableData = list.AsQueryable<Dummy>();
MethodCallExpression wherExpression =
                Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), 
                                "Where",
                                new Type[] { typeof(Dummy) }, 
                                queryableData.Expression,
                                Expression.Lambda<Func<Dummy, bool>>(lambda.Body, lambda.Parameters.First()));
```

**Update**: lambda.Body

`lambda.Body = {(((x.Title.Contains("Mihai") Or x.Description.Contains("Mihai")) Or x.Comments.Contains("Mihai")) Or x.User.Contains("Mihai"))}`

And then call the where expression  like:

```
var result = queryableData.Provider.CreateQuery<Dummy>(wherExpression).ToList();
```

The where clause builds properly and this is the result

```
{System.Collections.Generic.List`1[P.Dummy].Where(x => (((x.Title.Contains("Foo") Or x.Description.Contains("Foo")) Or x.Comments.Contains("Foo")) Or x.User.Contains("Foo")))}
```

When I try can call the where expression, I get

```
 var result = queryableData.Provider.CreateQuery<Dummy>(wherExpression).ToList();
 variable 'x' of type 'P.Dummy' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined
```

Do you have any idea why and could you help me fix it ?

**Update** 
This is how the expression is constructed:

```
var type = typeof(T);
var lambdaList = new List<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>();
foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties())
{
    if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(string))
    {
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");//{x}
        Expression expression = parameter;

        PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty(prop.Name);//Property
                expression = Expression.Property(expression, pi);//{x.Property}

         var containsFunc = Expression.Call(expression,
                    typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"),
                    new Expression[] { Expression.Constant("Mihai") });
                Expression<Func<T, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(containsFunc, parameter);
                lambdaList.Add(lambda);

     }
}
Expression<Func<T, bool>> finalExpression = lambdaList.First();

foreach (Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression in lambdaList.Skip(1))
{
   finalExpression = finalExpression.Or(expression);
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just call `Where` and pass just the inner expression inside? In any case, unwrapping a lambda expression is a bit more complicated than just using the same body and parameters :) What is it you *actually* want to do?

Comment: I do not have any control over the inner expression. I'm building it dynamically for different objects that have string properties. After I have my expression, I need to apply it to a list of the same type of objects and the ones used to construct the expression.

Comment: Okay, so you already have the inner expression. Just call `queryableData.Where(theInnerExpression)` and you're done :)

Comment: I already tried that, but the .where takes a Expression<Func<T,bool>> as an argument, while my innerExpression is a MethodCallExpression. `queryableData.Where(lambda.Compile())` this throws the same exception

Comment: Try to create only the lambda that passed to the where as Luaan mentioned. How do you create the lambda? Please show this code.

Comment: I see 2 "nice" alternatives, if i understand your problem correctly:
1.) Create an Interface that all possible objects use and that defines a method you can use for comparison. Then implement the correct body for each object.
2.) go over your list with a normal where expression, and for the expression body call a method that checks the type of the object and acts depending on that.

e.g. "is it of type x? return obj.Title.Contains(value)". Its way better readable than trying to do what you do

Comment: There are different types of objects that i want to build the where query, and the properties do not have the same name. for example `class Foo{string Name} and class Foo1{string Title}`

Comment: I got your problem. You create a new ParameterExpression for EACH property. They're all called `x` but they're different instances. Create only one ParameterExpression called `x` and then loop over all properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy of comment:

I got your problem. You create a new ParameterExpression for EACH property. They're all called x but they're different instances. Create only one ParameterExpression called x and then loop over all properties.